# Swap between multiple instances of ScriptableObjectInstaller procedurally

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

The documentation says that you can easily swap between multiple ScriptableObjectInstallers. And i think you do this by assigning needed ScriptableObjectInstaller of a same class in SceneContext.
But what if i want to procedurally decide which instance of a settings to use? Do i need to somehow procedurally change a reference to my SettingsInstaller in a scene context before i inject that settings where i need them? If so, how do i do that?

For example, i have 2 instances of a same SettingsInstaller: SettingsEasy and SettingsHard. How do i switch between them programmatically before injection? If i would have 2 instances of that settings in a scene context, then it's gonna throw me an error like this:

*ZenjectException: Found multiple matches when only one was expected for type 'MySettingsType' while building object with type 'ClassWhereIInjectingIt'.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this programmatically would be to install from a resource path like this:

```
public class GameSettingsInstaller : ScriptableObjectInstaller<GameSettingsInstaller>
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class MainInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public bool isHardDifficulty;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        GameSettingsInstaller.InstallFromResource(isHardDifficulty ? "SettingsHard" : "SettingsEasy", Container);
    }
}
```

Here, I'm assuming they are placed in a path that looks like `Resources/SettingsEasy` and `Resources/SettingsHard`

Comment: Ok. So in this case i'm not adding this installer to Scriptable Objects Installer placeholder on the Scene Context.

Comment: Exactly, yeah, no need in this case